# Looking for someone that is familiar with QNX 4.2

Tags: qnx

As per topic. I have very old machine that i cannot replace (some old railway machine). That machine still uses 3.5zip drive. I need to fit the USB instead. Therefore, as i`m completely not familiar with this system, can someone direct me please on where to start to reconfigure this ( if manageable of course) for use with USB? I guess there would a need for drivers etc so the USB is discoverable.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please reformat the question. I don't understand what do you want exactly?Why QNX is taged?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download io-usb (the USB server) and Fsys.usb (the USB bulk storage driver).

Start here:
http://foundry27.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.qnx4/wiki/InstallationNotesForUSBStack?selectedTab=versions&version=4

Continue here:
https://openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?t=11230

Comment: Thanks a lot in advace!!